# What does the event dispatch thread actually do?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-handling

I have read a statement "What the event dispatch thread actually does is run an OS-level message loop to be notified of UI events, then dispatch those events to the appropriate Swing components."

if this statement is true , it implies that when a button in a frame is clicked that event goes to the OS which is polling for the events which then dispatches them to the appropriate listeners.
What about event queue where it is managed at OS side or java application side?

Comment: is managed at Java application side

Answer (score 2):

The statement is incorrect if "OS-level" denotes some sort of magical native OS interaction. The EDT is just an ordinary thread. Native code receives events from the OS, and your handlers are called on the EDT. The mouse-click itself of course has to be communicated from software outside the JVM, but for a Swing button, anyway, the idea of a "Button" stays entirely inside the JVM.